# hide all panels except for active buffer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to toggle the current buffer (editor) so that it is the only one shown (hide all other panels)?  Basically, a "zoom" in on current panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*View → Toggle Zen Mode* sounds like what you're asking for. It was added in the [1.8 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_zen-mode).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that.  Pretty nice.  But If I have multiple buffers open in the same pane, they are still there.  I want it to hide the other buffers.

Comment: That doesn't seem possible right now. There's at least two open issues that describe what you're asking for: [#16927](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16927) and [#18421](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18421)